# Select only first n elements in operator form?

Tags: dataset

Is there any way to make `Select` take a second argument (to select only the first `n` elems) while in operator form?

It's too slow to perform the whole selection and then take the first `n`, for example:

```
dataset = 
  Dataset[Table[<|"a" -> RandomChoice[{1, 2}], "b" -> RandomReal[]|>, 
    1000000]];
Length@dataset[Select[#a == 1 & (*only want the first 1k found*)]]    
AbsoluteTiming[dataset[Select[#a == 1 &]][;; 1000];]    
AbsoluteTiming[Select[dataset, #a == 1 &, 1000];]
```

[image]

I don't want to put the dataset inside the Select like above, I'd like to use Dataset's single bracket query notation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alas, no -- at least not as long as we wish to use `Select` as a descending `Dataset`/`Query` operator.  The reason is that the query compiler will only recognize `Select` as a *descending* query operator when it has exactly one argument:

```
Needs["Dataset`"]

DescendingQ[Select[#==1&]]

(* True *)
```

Any attempt to curry other arguments will cause the expression to be interpreted as an *ascending* operator instead, as is the case for all functions that are not on the blessed list of descending operators:

```
op1 = Select[#, #==1&, 1000]&;
op2[c_, n_][l_] := Select[l, c, n]
op3[c_, n_] := Select[#, c, n] &
op4 = Curry[Select, {2, 3}];
op5 = Curry[{2, 3}][Select];

AscendingQ /@
  { op1
  , op2[#==1&, 1000]
  , op3[#==1&, 1000]
  , op4[#==1&, 1000]
  , op5[#==1&, 1000]
  }

(* {True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

We can see the difference using a small dataset:

```
ds = Range[10] // Dataset;
```

Contrast the action of the descending version of `Select`...

```
ds[Select[# < 4&], # + 100&]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

... with that of the ascending version:

```
ds[Select[#, # < 4 &, 3] &, # + 100 &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

In the descending version, the elements are first filtered and then added to 100.  In the ascending version, the elements are first added to 100 and *then* filtered.

We can often work around this situation by issuing consecutive queries:

```
ds[Select[#, # < 4 &, 3]&][All, # + 100&]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

or by using subqueries:

```
ds[Select[#, # < 4 &, 3] & /* Query[All, # + 100 &]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

*(A pedantic note: the `All` operators in these last queries are not strictly necessary given the listability of `Plus`, but they illustrate the general principle.)*

It is a shame that the query compiler does not have some special treatment for the `Curry` operator that was introduced in version 11.3.  It could be used to supplement and/or re-order the arguments to the various specially-recognized descending operators (especially `Select`, `SelectFirst`, and `GroupBy`).  Perhaps in some future version...

Comment: In version 12.1, _Curry_ has been renamed to _OperatorApplied_.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep the operator form, you could define a helper function to do this:

```
SelectSubset[crit_, n_][expr_] := Select[expr, crit, n]
```

Then:

```
r1 = dataset[SelectSubset[#a == 1&, 1000]]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = Select[dataset, #a == 1&, 1000]; //RepeatedTiming

Normal@r1 === Normal@r2
```

> {0.0029, Null}
>
> {0.0030, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 4):

Of course:

```
dataset[Select[#a == 1 &]][;; 1000]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Select[dataset, #a == 1 &, 1000]; // RepeatedTiming // First
dataset[data \[Function] Select[data, #a == 1 &, 1000]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.53
>
> 0.0030
>
> 0.0027

(Well, I don't know of a built-in method, but as it can be done like this, why should there be an extra built-in method? In the end, the operator forms are mere syntax sugar - sugar that has to be paid by a lot of documentation. (Btw., I usually do not hesitate to write longer code for better performance.))

Answer (score 1):

Unadvised solution:

```
Unprotect[Select];
Select[crit_, n_Integer] = Select[#, crit, n] &;
Protect[Select];
```

so that

```
Select[{1, 2, 3, 4}, GreaterThan[2], 1]
Select[GreaterThan[2], 1]@{1, 2, 3, 4}
% == %% (* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is simply
`Select[#, #a==1&, 1000]& @ dataset`. For example,

```
select1s[n_] := Select[#, #a==1&, n]&
select1s[1000] @ dataset
```

does what you want.